# drupal 7 SSL a lot of insecure urls

Tags: uri, ssl

My site is now using a SSL certificate but i have about 300k pages with insecure urls (http) - What is the best and most efficient way of fixing this problem?

The problem is the dynamic content is referencing HTTP content. The site is already forcing SSL.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! The _best and most efficient way_ is rather subjective. You should also make clear which insecure URLs you are seeing, since dynamic content is supposed to generate URLs using `l()`, which doesn't output absolute URLs in most of the cases.

Answer (score 3):

One solution, *if you're wanting to force your site to always to use SSL,* is to do it at the Apache level by adding this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

That's probably the *quickest way*. The *best way* is subjective; your needs might be different depending on priorities (e.g. for performance reasons you might want to force many static pages to HTTP).

Answer (score 1):

As Shawn Conn says, the easiest thing to do would be to force SSL for your entire site at the server level.  There is minimal performance overhead to SSL encryption for modern processors so if you've already paid for the certificate there's little reason not to do it.  Also this will prevent expensive application-level redirects to secure/un-secure pages as the case may be.

Comment: These don't solve the problem. The problem is the dynamic content is referencing HTTP content. The site is already forcing SSL.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Secure Pages](https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages) module.

> A small process which will redirect the required pages to a SSL version of the page.